# Awk if loop or not working

Tags: awk

Am trying to parse the below source file. Am trying to extract the text between===== and ENDTIME. 
And am using the code in a seperate block below. But when i use || to filter multiple patterns its not working. However when i use single pattern in awk if block its able to filter. 
Can someone let me know whats wrong with the command, why the or block is not working?

*Sourcefile:*

```
STARTTIME --- 2019/09/19 12:00:44
==================================================================
Processname                                Node   Status   QueueAv
==================================================================
RtpNm01                                   CE_01      run      full
RtpAcp01                                  CE_01      run      full
RtpDynManLite01                           CE_01      run      full
RtpDynLiteInc01                           CE_01      run      full
ENDTIME --- 2019/09/19 12:00:45
```

```
Expected Result:
RtpNm01                                   CE_01      run      full
RtpAcp01                                  CE_01      run      full
RtpDynManLite01                           CE_01      run      full
RtpDynLiteInc01                           CE_01      run      full
```

*Code:*

```
cat rtpServiceStatusrun | awk '/Processname\s*Node\s*Status\s*QueueAv/{
while (getline){
        if( $0 !~ /^====*/ || $0 !~ /^ENDTIME*/ ){
                        print $0
                }
        }
}'
```

Comment: can u plz share the expected result?

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and include the expect results in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using asterisk as though it were a wildcard.  It’s not.  Awk uses regex, not shell pattern matching.

Comment: What implementation of Awk are you using? AFAIK only `gawk` (GNU Awk) supports `\s` as a whitespace class.

Comment: AWK - GNU Awk 4.0.2. I dont have a problem with whitespace detection. I have problem in the or block of if statement.

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`? `cat file | grep "Rtp.*"` seems todo the same job if all your lines start with "Rtp".

Comment: Grep is pretty straight forward, but the data in $1 is dynamic it can be anything need not to start only Rtp Guillermo

Comment: @Wildcard posted the expected result in the question.

Comment: Well, one of the conditions `$0 !~ /^====*/` or `!~ /^ENDTIME*/` will always be true, surely? Perhaps what you intended was `if( ! ($0 ~ /^====/ || $0 ~ /^ENDTIME/) )`

Comment: I think you might do better to just use: `sed '1,4d;$d'` which seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: Maybe this is an `awk` alternative, assuming ENDTIME is the lat line: `awk 'NR>5 {print last} {last=$0}' `

Comment: will the first field always starts with alpha and ends with integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **many** ways to do this, including:

```
$ awk '/^ENDTIME/ {next}; NR>4' sourcefile 
RtpNm01                                   CE_01      run      full
RtpAcp01                                  CE_01      run      full
RtpDynManLite01                           CE_01      run      full
RtpDynLiteInc01                           CE_01      run      full
```

This prints all input lines **after** the fourth line, except for any line beginning with `ENDTIME`.

I think this is what you were trying to do with that weird `while (getline)` loop in the `/Processname\s*....../` block - there was no need to do that, awk already loops over every line of input, and you can test the value of NR (current input line number).

and:

```
awk '! /^(STARTTIME|ENDTIME|=====|Processname)/' sourcefile

grep -vE '^(STARTTIME|ENDTIME|=====|Processname)' sourcefile

sed -E -e '/^(STARTTIME|ENDTIME|=====|Processname)/d' sourcefile
```

All of these print any lines **not** matching the regexp.  They all use the same extended regular expression (ERE - default with `awk`, enabled with `-E` for both `grep` and `sed`), to look for any of the alternations at the beginning of the line (anchored with the `^`).

and:

```
sed -e '1,4d; $d' sourcefile
```

Delete the 1st to 4th lines and the last line.

Comment: thanks for giving me so many options. Am new to scripting and am a java developer basically. So the looping with while. Your answer is definitely a learning for me.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
cat file | head -n -1 | tail -n +5
```

Answer (score -2):

I changed or (||) to add (&&) and it started working.

```
cat rtpServiceStatusrun | awk '/Processname\s*Node\s*Status\s*QueueAv/{
while (getline){
        if( $0 !~ /^====*/ && $0 !~ /^ENDTIME*/ ){
                        print $0
                }
        }
}'
```

Comment: Still overcomplicated and if the $1 is truly dynamic, it could start with ENDTIME and you would never know.  See my sed snippet: `sed '1,4d;$d' rtpServiceStatusrun`

Comment: Got it.. But i want to process the file only when theres a header in this case, /Processname\s*Node\s*Status\s*QueueAv/ is there a easy way to do this in sed? am much familar with awk and sed am learning to use. so my approach.

Comment: is there sometimes not a header?  You didn’t mention that.  What are the constraints on the possible inputs?